# How to establish real time log output for running container when using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I'm working on a Django REST framework API that is built in a docker image and launched/managed with `docker-compose`. When I launch my app I get the real time log of the Django application in the terminal. I accidentally closed the terminal and I want to re-establish a real time log output in the terminal without restarting my containers.

I tried `docker-compose logs` which will print a `tail` of the log but does not re-establish a real time output. I would have to rerun this every time I wanted to see new log information.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--follow` option to the `logs` command?

Comment: @Steve Yup, that did the trick. If you put that information in an answer I’ll gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you add the --follow flag to your command, you'll get the desired result.  So:

```
docker-compose logs --follow ...
```